# Recovery corrupted file

Tags: windows, file, visual-studio-2017, corruption

My PC recently crashed, I had to change the mother board and now it works fine.

I opened my Visual Studio to check a project, but I have 2 files (with pending changes) that can't be opened.

I have try to open one with notepad++ and it is full of unreadable characters. So I opened it with WinHex, the files contains only 00:

[image]

Is there a way to get back my files ?

Comment: There are many ways that **might** be able to do it, but there is absolutely no guarantee. Did you have backup? Version control? Can you try using a program that recovers deleted files? If no such options are available or work, and the file is really important, there are companies that specialize in recovering data from disks. However, most likely the file is lost.

Comment: Additionally, I want to single out one part of my other comment: Do you have/use version control? If the answer to that is "no", then my #1-#10 advices would be: Set it up, create an account on github and start using git.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I have a version control, but I did not checked in modifications before the crash. This crash concern a few modifications but I don't want to redo all my work from yesterday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What was in the file? Source code? Perhaps Visual Studio [kept an autorecover version](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saraford/2008/02/14/did-you-know-where-visual-studio-saves-auto-recovered-files-in-the-case-of-an-unexpected-shutdown-151/).

If not, you'll have to redo your work from the previous version found in source control or backups.

If you don't even have *that*, now's the time to start working with source control and backups.

Comment: Thanks to you I recovered some of the files but not all. My previous version is still on TFS, but it is always hard to remember what I have done since last checkin.

Comment: After verification, the files I can't find in backup folder has no pending changes. So I recover all my work. Thank you !